# Взаимодействие Frame'ов.

Tags: jframe, java

Имеются 2 Frame. На одном есть таблица, на другом - кнопка. Требуется при нажатии на кнопку добавить в таблицу запись. Говорят: "используй ActionListener", но я даже примерно не представляю, как это должно выглядеть. Можно пример кода?

---

Frame1:

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel();

public Frame1() {
    initComponents();

    data.addColumn("A");
    data.addColumn("B");
    jTable1.setModel(data);
}
```

Frame2:

```
public class Frame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Frame1 fr;

public Frame2(final Frame1 fr) {
    this.fr = fr;
    initComponents();

    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    fr.data.addRow(new Object[] {1, 2});    
} 
});
}
```

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame1().setVisible(true);
        new Frame2(new Frame1()).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: почитай про swing

Comment: Что почитать, где почитать? Мне прекрасно известно про Swing, я его использую, так что это вообще никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет. А вопрос в том, как мне использовать ActionListener в ДАННОМ случае. Если есть что сказать - говорите, нет - идите мимо. Все просто.

Comment: что тебе известно про swing? как обрабатывать нажатия? это основы которые с первых страниц книг идут, в примерах, где надо что-то вывести по нажатия кнопки, есть код: button.setOnClickListener(this); в любой книге по джаве есть примеры

Comment: зачем вы ВООБЩЕ фреймы используете?

Comment: Ну какбэ курсовую пишу, а зачем вообще фреймы используются?

Comment: To Gorets: А вы вообще читали, что я написал в вопросе? Мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку в одном Frame, произвести некоторые действия в другом. Если это основы и "идут с первых страниц книг" скажите в какой книге подобное описано.

Comment: а ну да великие и ужасные курсовые... делайте бред который никому не нужен, потому.... что это сложно и никому не нужно

Comment: Бред потому что ты не знаешь ответа на этот вопрос?

Comment: ну покажи код фреймов, так уж и быть, покажу как с одного в другой чето передать по нажатию кнопки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значит так. Во-первых, как навесить `ActionListener`? Примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java):

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // этот код будет вызван при нажатии кнопки
    } 
});
```

Затем, что делать при нажатии кнопки в этом самом `ActionListener`'е? Надо добавить данные в `TableModel`. У вас сейчас `TableModel` хранится во `Frame1`. Концептуально это неверно, ну да бог с ним. Ваш код `ActionListener`'а лежит во `Frame2`, значит, `Frame2` должен иметь ссылку на `Frame1`. (Вообще-то, конечно, бизнес-логику надо полностью вывести из UI-кода, но это на будущее.)

Итак, для начала `Frame2` должен иметь ссылку на экземпляр `Frame1`. И в этом самом `ActionListener`'е вызвать оттуда публичную функцию, которая и обновит `TableModel`.

Всё ясно?

PS: а зачем вам *две* функции `main`? Одна из них же не отработает.

Comment: А как правильно получить ссылку на экземпляр Frame1?

Comment: @Сергей1991: как угодно. Например, передайте в конструкторе.

Comment: Что-то типо Frame1 fr = new Frame1?

Comment: Нет, что-то типо 

    public Frame2(Frame1 f1)
    {
        this.f1 = f1;
        initComponents();
    }

Comment: @Сергей1991: Вы хотите, чтобы я телепатически узнал, что именно не получается? Или объясняйте, с кодом и сообщениями об ошибках, или дальше сами.

Comment: @Сергей1991: ну так код покамест правильный, а что именно не работает?

Comment: Не происходит добавление данных в таблицу

Comment: @Сергей1991: странно, вы уверены, что вы нигде не ошиблись? А как вы вызываете конструктор Frame2?

Comment: @Сергей1991: ну, включите голову же! Вы создаёте и показываете один экземпляр Frame1, а в Frame2 передаёте другой. Догадаетесь сами, что надо сделать?

Comment: Догадываюсь. Все, сделал. Большое спасибо за помощь - не каждому бы хватило терпения)) А я тупил как мог))

Comment: @Сергей1991: ура, одолели! :-) Хорошего остатка выходных.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame1 frame1 = new Frame1();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        Frame2 frame2 = new Frame2(frame1);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Может, кому-нибудь ещё поможет...